# How to begin enumerate with a lowercase b?

Tags: enumerate

I want to create an enumerate, that starts with lowercase b, and each next item is the next lowercase letter. So, it goes like b, c, d, e, and so on. I have the following code segment, but it makes all the items b).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[b)]
\item This is a b)
\item This is also a b)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{enumerate}[a)]\setcounter{enumi}{1}` -- You have to increase the counter first

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the usual `enumerate` environment or with `enumerate` from the package of the same name, one has to increase the `enumi` (the first level) counter first, to get another start value. Since the `\item` macro increases the counter again, `\setcounter{enumi}{1}` is the correct way. here.

The usual `enumerate` environment however does not provide for `a)` without redefinition of `\theenumi`.

The shorthand version of the label 'template' are just working for the starting values `a)`, `A)` etc. only, `b)` means ... well **b)** ;-)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[a)]\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item This is a b)
\item This is now a c)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

With `enumitem`, it's a little bit more `logical`;

Using `shortlabels` as the package option, the `short hand` version of `enumerate` can be used, the `start=2` will set the correct starting value of the counter.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),start=2]
\item This is a b)
\item This is now a c)
\end{enumerate}

Short interruption

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),resume]
\item This is a d)
\item This is now a e)
\end{enumerate}

  

\end{document}
```

Please note that the `enumitem` has a resume facility, that allows for interruption of a list and continuing later on.

[image]

Comment: The explanation is, that `a`, `i`, `I`, and  `1` are merely patterns for the `enumerate` an get replaced by the `alph`, `roman`, `Roman`, and `arabic` counters, respectively. For example `[AIT]` counts as `AIT`, `BIIT`, `CIIIT`, `DIVT`,...

Comment: @Ronny: Thanks, I wanted to add this explanation myself ;-)

Comment: Might be an idea to add an example of the resume, if I'm not mistaken you'll need `resune*` in this case, which might be confusing to new users.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the beautiful and fast answer.

Comment: @daleif: Hm, I thought so too, but just `resume` is sufficient. Perhaps due to the `shortlabels` option?

Comment: @pixel: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!